# Why did the monkey remain undead in Pirates of the Carribbean?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, curse-of-the-black-pearl, dead-mans-chest

Even after the curse was lifted in the first movie, Barbosa's monkey Jack remains undead.

In Dead Man's chest, Jack trades the monkey with the witch and shot him and pronounced him as undead.

How is that possible?

Comment: i think you missed the seen where monkey took a coin as said by `Arremer`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

At the end of "Curse of the Black Pearl", after the credits, there is a scene where Jack (monkey) **takes a coin** from the chest - getting himself cursed again, similar to what Captain Jack Sparrow did during the fight with Barbossa.

Sparrow took the coin during the fight which he returned later, Jack (monkey) on the other hand **didn't return it**. He had probably hidden it with his other shiny things or lost it somewhere, he is a monkey after all.

[Jack's complete story](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Jack_%28monkey%29).

Comment: yeah but even if you consider the after end credits scene, the curse has been lifted so why does the monkey have the curse placed upon him

Comment: He took the coin from the chest and got cursed again,he was fine before that.

Answer (score 5):

Have you watched the after credit scene in the first film? That's where the monkey steals another coin.